# Running rails app from a subDir on Apache with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I've already spent a few hours thoroughly trying to find an answer. The guys from Site5 who provide the hosting hit a wall.

What I'm trying to do: Run the reils app from playplanit[dot]com/sfcal and not from playplanit[dot]com/.

The current setup:
- The app itself is here: /home/playplan/apps/ppi/current/
- In .htaccess file
    PassengerEnabled on
    PassengerAppRoot /home/playplan/apps/ppi/current
- The public files are in the public_html (previously the were here /home/playplan/apps/ppi/current/public and public_html was a sym link, but I changed that because the whole point of making this change is so that I can run a Wordpress blog in the docRoot

What has been tried:
- Creating a sym link: sfcal/ -> /home/playplan/apps/ppi/current/public
- Adding RailsBaseURI /sfcal to .htaccess file
- Attempting to change all 'paths' in routes.rb
    Here's the rake routes output after paths I could think to change where changed: http://cl.ly/2N2Q2z0N332v2B2F3r38
- I thought that maybe map.root need to be changed somehow, but couldn't and then one of the technicians helping me added this line to environment.rb: config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/sfcal"
- Accoring to them nothing needs to be change in the httpd.conf file
- I've also tried restarting the app by creating a restart.txt file in tmp/

I know that the sym link works, but something in the app recognizes that it's a subDir and will serve up a 404 that sits in the 'public' dir.

Any ideas of what else needs configuring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check Passenger documentation [Deploying to a sub URI](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri).

**EDIT**

All you need is to follow Passenger documentation. Your needn't mess with rails routes or move you application `public` folder.

Suppose you have you rails app deployed to `/home/playplan/apps/ppi/current` and `/home/playplan/public_html` directory is root of your virtual host with following Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName playplanit.com
  DocumentRoot /home/playplan/public_html
  <Directory /home/playplan/public_html>
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

To have your application accessible from http://playplanit.com/sfcal your need to do following:

- Make sure that Apache `Options FollowSymLinks` and `AllowOverride Options` is enabled in httpd.conf for your `VirtualHost` or following won't work.
- Create link named as `sfcal` in `public_html` directory pointing to your rails `public` directory.

`ln -s /home/playplan/apps/ppi/current/public /home/playplan/public_html/sfcal`

- Add following to `/home/playplan/public_html/.htaccess`

  ```
  RailsBaseURI /sfcal
  ```
- Place following into `/home/playplan/public_html/sfcal/.htaccess`

  ```
  Options -MultiViews
  ```

Comment: AlexD, thanks. however, that is one of the first resources I tried and the folks at Site5 (host) told me I didn't need mess with that, that it was 'automated'. They proceeded to add a line (shown in this reference RailsBaseURI into the .htaccess file, but that didn't seem to do the trick. Can such line be added to the .htaccess file or does it HAVE to be added to the httpd.conf? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks AlexD…I tried the above in the .htaccess file and I get an Internal Server Error if I add the '<Directory …' part. I don't think that's allowed syntax in an .htaccess file. I looked over the Passenger docs and it's asking you to add the above line in the apache conf file. The problem is I CAN'T do that according to the Site5 people. Adding RailsBaseURI seems to make no difference. The problem continues to be a 404. I'm trying to twist Site5's arm so they somehow let me configure apache conf file.

Comment: This is my mistake with <Directory>, you need to move `Options -MultiViews` to separate .htaccess in /home/playplan/public_html/sfcal/ directory. In apache httpd.conf you need to have only `Options FollowSymLinks` and `AllowOverride Options`. I have updated answer again.

Comment: OK…still doesn't seem to apply/work…here's all that I've changed: in sfcal/.htaccess I've added 'Options -MultiViews'; in public_html/.htaccess I have 'RailsBaseURI /sfcal
PassengerEnabled on
PassengerAppRoot /home/playplan/apps/ppi/current' …… in environment.rb I have added the following lines: 'ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/sfcal"' AND 'config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/sfcal"' …… FINALLY, I've restarted everything and I still get the 404. No change seems to affect the app running from public_html. When do I get to shoot myself ;)

Comment: It is strange that you are getting 404s. Could you access static files like `favicon.ico` or `robots.txt` in /sfcal/?

Comment: @AlexD yes, I can see those files: http://playplanit.com/sfcal/robots.txt and http://playplanit.com/sfcal/favicon.ico